# Meaning of 「そのまま入れるから」 in this context

Tags: translation

I know the general meaning of 「そのまま」, but I can't thing of anything appropriate it could mean in this situation. The dialog goes something like this:

> A：鳴海だ。
>   A: Oh, it's Narumi.
>
> B：おはよう。
>   B: Good morning.
>
> A：荷造り？
>   A: Are you packing up?
>
> B：そう、もう使わない教科書とか早めにまとめとかないと。
>   B: Yeah, I thought I could collect the textbooks I won't be needing any more ahead of time.
>
> A：手伝うよ。鳴海、指ケガしてんじゃん。
>   A: I'll help you. Your finger is hurt after all.
>
> B：でももうほとんど終わって…あ。
>   B: But I'm nearly done... ah.
>
> A：あーホラそのまま入れるから。
>   A: ???
>
> A：ヒモとかで縛んないと。
>   A: You have to tie them (the books) together with something like a thread.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The handwritten onomatopoeia 「ぐら」 is the hint.

> 「ぐら」＝「ぐらぐら」＝ the "sound" of things moving or shaking unsteadily.

That is what is happening to the textbooks thrown into the bag.

> 「そのまま入{い}れるから」 means:
>
> "(That is because) you put them just as they are into the bag (without tying them up first)."